# Validate PropTypes passed component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a question about propTypes. If you look at LoginLayoutRoute.propTypes how can I validate the component is being passed.

```
const LoginLayoutRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={matchProps => (
      <LoginLayout>
        <Component {...matchProps} />
      </LoginLayout>
    )}
  />
)

LoginLayoutRoute.propTypes = {
  component: ...,
}

const RouterSetup = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <LoginLayoutRoute path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. It looks like this:

```
LoginLayoutRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```